# What is shortest distance between 2 nodes in a matrix?

Tags: tree, matrix, nodes, units-of-measurement

I have a matrix 5x5 (25 nodes). Is there a formula that I can find the shortest distance between 2 node i and j in the matrix ?

Note: distance between 1 node and its neighbor is 1 unit.

=================

In my observation, there are many paths with the same distance between those 2 nodes i and j
so i'm not sure if there is a formula to calculate the shortest one? I appreciate if anybody can help. Thanks.

Ex:

```
* * * i *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* j * * *
```

Shortest distance between i and j is 6 units.

Comment: What distance, what's a neighbour? How about posting an example of what you are looking for?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to calculate the shortest distance or the shortest path? Are you able to move diagonally or only in x/y direction?

Comment: there are several measures you can use

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance

Comment: @sebastiangeiger: only in x/y direction

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of these two nodes in the grid? (Don't say "matrix", that means something else.)

Comment: when there is no heart, there is no short distance."Newton"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is the `L1` distance, also called the [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance). So if your two nodes have matrix indices `(i1,j1)` and `(i2,j2)`, then the shortest distance between them is `|i1-i2|+|j1-j2|`.

This is of course, assuming you can't move diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the normal [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) would work just fine.  Get the X,Y difference between where you are and where you want to go; this will give you a negative or positive value.  From this you should be able to move up/down left/right as needed until you are in the same row/column.  Couldn't figure out how to get superscript; but this will work.

```
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
```

Comment: this is usually termed euclidean distance

Comment: I did not realize that the distance had a name; I merely know about the formula used to find it.  Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [**Metric Space**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space)